# What is the correct error code for timeout?

Tags: html, http, http-headers, http-status-codes

I am developing a website and it will display a page for 5 minutes and user will be redirected to an error page which ask them to refresh the page. What status code should I put in the error page?

I am expecting the suitable error code to be displayed in the error page.

Edit: The page is displaying sensitive information so I want to add a timeout for security purpose.

Comment: Why would this be an error page? Normally, developers want to _avoid_ errors, not _cause_ them.

Comment: FTR: What seems to be the closest to what you asked for is [504 Gateway Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504), even if I'm unsure about what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Why not just refresh for them instead of redirecting to an annoying and pointess error page?

Comment: @SebastianSimon  The page displays sensitive information. I just think of it as a security so it would not be active if user forgot to close the page.

Comment: What you want is not really an "error", but rather a simple redirect on a *safer* page (or *less sensitive*, according to you). I don't see the need for an HTTP status code, simply because there is no HTTP communication involved (it's a client-side code that brings the user on another page after a given time, nothing more)

Comment: @indyteo Should it be a session timeout message?

Comment: @muhammaddanish What exactly do you mean by “a session timeout message”?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Instead of putting error code, I put Session Timeout as header in the redirected page

Comment: @muhammaddanish I’m really not sure which [HTTP header](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) you mean. I’m also not sure what benefit you’re hoping to get from doing this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find HTTP response codes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses

Depending of what are doing, you might send a code 408 (request time) or 504 (gateway timeout)

If you explain a bit more of your problem, it might be possible to give you better orientation. Regards